# How do I make a favicon?

Tags: web, favicon

How can I fix my new tabs and new windows so that they will display the icon of my site? Currently they display the bluehost default icon.

My normal page icon:

```
<link rel="icon" href="protectedImages/faviconS.gif" type="image/gif" sizes="16x16" />
```

My displayed images' target=_blank link:

```
<td style="text-align:center;"><a href="'.$num.'" target="_blank"><img src="'.$num.'" width ="'.($width/4).'" alt="random image"></a>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put a favicon.ico graphic file in the document root of your webserver.  For BlueHost, put it in your public_html folder.

To create a facivon.ico file, you can search Google for "favicon generator". and go to a site like http://www.favicon.cc/ to generate it.

Comment: I placed the icon in the public_html folder, but it still shows up as a bluehost icon. I verified that mine replaced the bluehost icon.

Comment: Geez... there it is. Thanks for the help everyone